# encrypting connection string in java

Tags: java, encryption, connection-string

I need to know how to encrypt a connection string in Java.
In ASP.NET you the connection string is saved in the web.config file, and you can encrypt it.
But how can I do it in Java?

Comment: You can use different algorithms to encrypt the string like SHA, MD5 as per your requirement.

Comment: @Sunny Since when are `SHA` and `MD5` encryption algorithms? Encryption is, by definition, reversible. These are hashing algorithms which are, by definition, non reversible.

Comment: Where do you want to store the connection string? Why do you want to encrypt it?

Comment: I don't really know where can I store it, is there a configuration file in Java like web.config in .NET?

Comment: You may want to tag your question with `.net` as I have absolutely no idea what a `Web.config` file is and I image many Java developers are in the same position.

Comment: I am half expecting you mean the data-source configuration which is set up on the container via the Admin console in JBOSS or Weblogic Console ?

Comment: The web.config part of this question is totally unnecessary, this questions should just be "How do I encrypt a connection sting in java"